# Let V be vector space over field F. T is a linear transformation from V to V. Then prove that T is invertible if and only if T is one to one and onto

Tags: linear-algebra

If F and G are inverse of each other then F(G) =G(F) =I.  Is it engough to prove that F and G are surjective and injective

Answer (score 1):

I think  invertibility of a LT $T$ means there exist a LT $S$ such that $ST=TS=I$. So you also have to verify that the inverse function is  a linear map. Can you do this?

Answer (score 0):

What conditions do you think that you must satisfy $T$ to be an invertible linear transformation? Should it be a square matrix? Should it have left and right inverses?

A start would be consider to $Dim(Nullspace(T))=0$ (trivial kernel) thus $T : V \to V$ and every pair $u,v \in V$ is associated by $u \mapsto T(u)$ then $T(u)=v$. Moreover, define $T^{-1} : V \to V$ and the same applies by $v \mapsto T^{-1}(v)$ thus $T^{-1}(v)=u$.

Answer (score 0):

Linear transformations are specific kinds of functions. For any function, the existence of an inverse function is guaranteed by the properties of being both surjective and injective. So yes, these two properties are sufficient to prove that an inverse exists.

Note that this does not *in itself* guarantee that the inverse function is also a linear transformation.